# Determining optimal number of threads for Metal on Apple GPUs?

Tags: ios, multithreading, metal, apple-m1

I've looked over Apple's [Metal Feature Sets](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf), however, I do not see any way to determine the number of GPU cores available.

My hunch is I should perform a similar number of threads as there are cores. For instance, if there are 4 GPU cores, 4 threads seems ideal.

Each thread needs its own command encoder (for example: `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`) and there is overhead for updating state changes and binding buffers, so at some point performance would drop off sharply.

Would I have to hard code the number of cores based on the chip information (eg `A12`, `M1`)?

Is there a rule of thumb for how many threads are optimal for a given `MTLGPUFamily` or other available device information?

UPDATE: this is my pipeline. If I have `particleCount` set to say 4,000,000 running in a single command encoder, on a single thread, it will render at about 1/4 the speed as when I have `particleCount` set to 1,000,000 running on 4-threads (on a 4-core device).

It is working with a 1-D buffer that is the same length as the `particleCount`. `numberParticles` is the number of particles calculated in the compute kernel.

```
guard let computeBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else {print("computeBuffer nil"); return }
guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else {print("commandBuffer nil"); return }
guard let computeEncoder = computeBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() else {print("computeEncoder nil"); return }

let renderDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
renderDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store

let width = computePipelineState.threadExecutionWidth
let threadsPerGroup = MTLSizeMake(width, 1, 1)

// usual computeEncoder buffers, textures binding here

if metalDevice.supportsFeatureSet(.iOS_GPUFamily4_v1) {
    dispatchThreads(particleCount: Int(particleCount))
} else {
    let threads = min(computePipelineState.threadExecutionWidth, Int(particleCount))
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: threads, height: 1, depth: 1)
    let groups = Int(particleCount) / threads + 1
    let groupsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: groups, height: 1, depth: 1)
    computeEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(groupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
}

computeEncoder.endEncoding()
computeBuffer.commit()
computeBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

guard let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderDescriptor) else {reportCritical("renderEncoder_nil");  return}

// usual renderEncoder buffers, textures binding here

renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: Int(numberParticles))

renderEncoder.endEncoding()
commandBuffer.commit()
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the inline dispatch function:

```
let width = computePipelineState.threadExecutionWidth
let threadsPerGroup = MTLSizeMake(width, 1, 1)
    
func dispatchThreads(particleCount: Int) {
    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSizeMake(particleCount, 1, 1)
    computeEncoder.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerGroup)
}
```

Comment: Why does each thread need its own command encoder? As far as I know, you just push a lot of work to the GPU at once and let it handle the scheduling—no need to split the work on the CPU side. Also, did you check this out? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/calculating_threadgroup_and_grid_sizes

Comment: For multi-processing with metal I am fairly certain that each thread needs to be on its own command encoder to handle multi-threaded operations. The link you referenced is about dispatchThreads and groups, not about having multiple encoders on different cores.

Comment: As [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandqueue): "Command queues are thread-safe and allow multiple outstanding command buffers to be encoded simultaneously."

Comment: I think that means that you can schedule work for the GPU from different threads concurrently because each command buffer is a self-contained work unit. As for the cores: at least in CUDA, the work scheduler can distribute work items from the same thread group among multiple cores. It decides how many cores to actually involve. It may even switch between different work items to hide I/O latency. But if you have one big command buffer with a lot of work items (and the GPU has the capacity), Metal should schedule the work among all available cores—even when only using one queue.

Comment: Interesting, but hmm, it doesn't seem to work that way. If I make one buffer with say 4,000,000 particles, it will render 1/4 the speed of putting it in 4 command encoders with 1,000,000 particles each on 4 threads.

Comment: Uh, ok, very interesting. Then it seems a thread grid is always executed on a single GPU core. Sorry, I might have misremembered the CUDA semantics or it's really different in Metal...

Comment: That's OK, I appreciate you trying to help!

Comment: Generally speaking, the GPU driver can and does schedule different GPU cores to perform parts of the same dispatch. There may be special cases in which it can't, or the performance would actually drop if it would. It's almost impossible to say without seeing a minimal code example, but my first guesses would be around resource contention, memory layout, synchronization or non-trivial resource dependencies.

Comment: Please see updated question with code, thank you. If there is anything else that would be helpful to see, just let me know and I will add it.

Comment: What does `dispatchThreads(particleCount: Int(particleCount))` do? Presumably it's a method you wrote...? I'm assuming you're testing on a device with GPU family >=4...

Comment: Correct assumptions, and I added the inline dispatch function to the question.